# Factors to numeric while conserving level order

Tags: r, type-conversion, numeric, factors

I know there are lots of questions regarding this and I searched for a solution, but unfortunately I do not get what I need...:

I have a mixed data frame with factors and numeric variables. I *need all factors as numeric*.
I found a solution to convert them, but it is important to still know **which number refers to which level. More precisely, I want the reference level to have the lower number (e.g. 1), and the other level/s the higher number.**

This example illustrates my question:

```
data <- data.frame(group = c("case", "control", "case", "control"), height = c(167, 200, 166, 180), diabetes = c("yes", "no", "no", "yes"))
data$group <- as.factor(data$group)
data$diabetes <- as.factor((data$diabetes))
data$group <- relevel(data$group, ref="control")
levels(data$group)
str(data)

i <- sapply(data, is.factor)
data[i] <- lapply(data[i], as.numeric)

str(data)
```

In the column group, control is the reference, which is important. When I look at levels everything makes sense, it comes first.
However, control is assigned level 2, and case level 1, which also becomes clear when I convert to numeric.

I am confused by this behavior, can anyone tell me how I can assign control the "1" and case "2" (also for other columns in my real data frame). And maybe why this is happening??

Comment: As a default, the levels are numbered alphabetically. So, if you can change the characters to `c("experiment","control","experiment","control")`, your problem is solved. Otherwise, you can recode the category you want to be lowest as value `0`. Or, in your example, just write `data$group = 3-data$group` to flip the values 1 and 2.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your answer! Indeed, I knew that R behaves like this, but I explicitly releveled the factor to have control as ref category. Therefore, I don't know why R does not consider this when I change to numeric..